# Why JavaScript Math.random() returns same number multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, math

I have an array with two items and I need to random a choice of this items but the most of times I get the same item from array...

See the code:

```
var numbers = Array(523,3452);
var choice = numbers[Math.floor(Math.random()*numbers.length)];
console.log("Choice:", choice);
```

How can I avoid this kind of behavior?

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: groups is not defined`

Comment: You know that `Array(523, 3452)` is just `[523, 3452]`? So you may need a lot of tries to get the other number.

Comment: **numbers** contain only two elements only 523 and 3452. What else do you expect to return other than these two?

Comment: The **`Math.random()`** function returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the range 0–1 (inclusive of 0, but not 1) with **approximately uniform distribution over that range** — which you can then scale to your desired range. The implementation selects the initial seed to the random number generation algorithm; it cannot be chosen or reset by the user. `--->` **[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)**

Comment: "How can I avoid this kind of behavior?"   Exactly what sort of behavior are you expecting in its place?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Yes, only two items... and that is the point, I'd like something like a round robin if the number os items was less then 3

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir How in the world so? The code works exactly as intended. There is no problem, yet OP claims there is one.

Comment: A round robin is not random. A round robin can be achieved with an index number that you increase, until you've reached the total number of elements in your array and then just start over at 0. To get proper answers, I'd suggest that you update your question stating the exact outcome you want.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. `Math.random`, in all implementations known to me, passes simple statistic tests. As such, it will **not** have a bias towards either choice in normal applications.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir why do you think that? His opening words are "I have an array with two items".

Comment: @ASDFGerte My bad.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Random numbers can appear in streaks; that's part of being random. But over time the [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) should take over and even out those streaks. You can test that easily enough by running this a bunch of times and counting:

```js
var numbers = Array(523,3452);
let counts = [0,0]

for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    let choice = numbers[Math.floor(Math.random()*numbers.length)];
    if (choice ===  523) counts[0]++
    else if (choice == 3452) counts[1]++
}

// counts should be about even
console.log(counts);
```

Comment: *Random numbers can appear in streaks; that's part of being random.* - love explaining that to the business sometimes.

Comment: My first run they were both `5000`!

Comment: Wow, you could actually get the [reversal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal) badge for this.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Hmm, getting exactly 5000 is a fairly low probability event ... it is, if I'm not mistaken, (10000 choose 5000)/2^10000 which appears to be approximately 8e-3.

Answer (score 0):

The `Math.random()` function returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the range 0–1 (inclusive of 0, but not 1) with approximately uniform distribution over that range — which you can then scale to your desired range.

`Math.random() * 2` will give range 0 to 1.99999999999999 but not 2. `Math.floor(0...1.999999999999)` will either return 0 or 1 with 50% chance similar to a coin.

`numbers[0`] will give 523 and `numbers[1]` will give 3452

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem like the original question. What helped me was [rando.js](https://github.com/nastyox/Rando.js)

```
var numbers = Array(523,3452);
var choice = numbers[rando(0, numbers.length - 1)]; // Array item index is generated randomly.
console.log("Choice:", choice);
```

Another way would be with [underscore.js](https://underscorejs.org/#random)

```
var numbers = Array(523,3452);
var choice = numbers[_.random(0, numbers.length - 1)]; // Array item index is generated randomly.
console.log("Choice:", choice);
```