# Generate random string with given variables

Tags: javascript

So my task is to generate random string with k words in it, word letter count randomized from m(min) and n(max).

Practically I've done everything, I just can't understand why `Math.random()` function gives the same number every time, that's why randomized word count doesn't work, it always goes for the same letter count in every k word.

Here is my code:

```
// Random string with more given variables
function randomStringIntermediate(){
    var m = parseInt(prompt("How many random letters in a word(min)"));
    var n = parseInt(prompt("How many random letters in a word(max)"));
    var k = parseInt(prompt("How many words in a string"));
    var letters = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    var p = document.getElementById("p9");
    var word = "";
    for(j = 0; j < k; j++){
        word += " "
        for(i = 0; i < (Math.floor(Math.random()) + m) * (n-m); i++){
            var letter =  letters.charAt(Math.random() * letters.length);
            word += letter;
        }
    }
    p.innerHTML = word;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why JavaScript Math.random() returns same number multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51564360/why-javascript-math-random-returns-same-number-multiple-times)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your word count:

```
(Math.floor(Math.random()) + m) * (n-m)
```

The term `Math.floor(Math.random()) + m` will always be `m`, because, according to [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random):

> The Math.random() function returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the range 0–1 (inclusive of 0, but not 1)

You probably meant for your parenthesis to close at the end :)

Comment: Thank you for explaining with details.

Comment: What a simple mistake by my side, I was laughing for a while, sometimes the brain gets that tired to make mistakes like this.

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
(Math.floor(Math.random()) + m) * (n-m)
```

to

```
(Math.floor(Math.random() * (n-m) + m))
```

Comment: Plus add Math.floor(...) at letters.charAt()