# What could cause Math.random() to generate the same "random" number on every page reload?

Tags: javascript, typescript, random, electron

I'm making an electron app and in the renderer process I have a method that calls Math.random(). Just a simple `return Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)`, nothing special.
The problem is that it literally returns the same numbers every time I run the app. 541, 271, 919, 284.. etc. Every time I re-open the app, it's the same numbers in the same order.

What could be the cause of this?

EDIT: 
This is a weird issue. After some testing I marked down that

- the issue persist only in the renderer process (written in typescript and compiled using webpack).
- `window.crypto.getRandomValues(array)` works as expected.

Comment: This is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51564360/why-javascript-math-random-returns-same-number-multiple-times

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why JavaScript Math.random() returns same number multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51564360/why-javascript-math-random-returns-same-number-multiple-times)

Comment: I believe that's not the case. My app literally returns the same values 100% of the time. I believe it's an issue with electron. I would provide some sample code but it's just a dead simple react component with a random number between 1-1000 as a state.

Comment: The RNG is probably seeded the same way every time. This might be some sort of debug option somewhere.

Comment: What's calling your simple method? Could we have a bit of context?

Comment: I tested `for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) console.log(Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000))` in my app.tsx (renderer process). It returns the same numbers in sequence every run. Not the case for main.js (main process) though, for which it's random as expected.

Comment: tested => as in a unit test? if so could you post the code. I agree with @VLAZ that seeding might have something to do with it.

Comment: "Tested" as in putting the code at the root of app.tsx (which is compiled by webpack) and then running the electron app. I too believe this is a seeding issue. Isn't the seeding based on time though, which would be different every time?

Comment: Interestingly this suggests that the seed *cannot* be set by application code -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random -- so what would happen if you deleted whatever webpack compiled, recompiled it, and ran again?

Comment: Recompiling the code didn't help. I have no idea how this is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that calling cryptico.generateRSAKey() calls seedrandom.js's Math.seedrandom(), which overrides Math.random().

Case closed. Related:
https://github.com/wwwtyro/cryptico/issues/20